# Choose precision current source mosfet and opamp

Tags: current-source

I am working on simple precision current source figure below, I need figure out how to choose correct Opamp and Mosfet to have most accurate result (Linear).

So how do I calculate (or choose) Opamp and Mosfet requirement , to be able to get 1nA to 1uA.

[image]
[image] Green Is current and Red is input voltage

The R1 value could be change (Iout = Vin/R1) but I am more interested on linearity and choosing correct Opamp and Mosfet.

Vin = 0-3V variable (From DAC)

Comment: Product recommendations are off topic here and aren't useful to future readers.

Comment: I am not looking for product recommendation I am looking for, how do I calculate these requirements for opamp and Mosfet.

Comment: What Vout range is required and Io vs Vin specs?  Then why assume this is the best way to meet your specs?

Comment: Maybe this is not the best way to do it, but still want to know how do you figure out op amp and mosfet requirements. I am using DAC to generate 0-3V to opamp and I need Iout of 1nA to 1uA.

Comment: I removed the part of your question that made it sound like a shopping question.

Comment: How accurate does the 1 nA need to be. Ditto the 1 uA?

Comment: I don't think you need the pass transistor. It's only 10uA max and it's also running off 3.3 V just like the op-amp so it's not really doing anything that the op-amp couldn't be doing on its own.

Comment: @Andy in1nA -10nA  accuracy is not that important but after 10nA I want something between 0.5% - 1% it will be acceptable.

Comment: Choose an opamp whose combined error of input offset voltage and input bias current (into the load resistor) produces a voltage error across the load resistor of less than 1 % When trying to produce 10 nA. Report what you calculate that to be. Then try and find a MOSFET that has a leakage current that is very, very, very, very small. Good luck. You’ll find that you will likely be better off using a BJT although it might still be flaky.

Comment: You are looking for an amplfiier with very low Vos, with *really* low Ib and Ios. The actual pass device can be  compensated by the amplifier itself but it will require a *very* low Vgs rating which you may struggle to find. A bipolar transistor might be more suitable here. As @Andyaka notes, you need to calculate what the actual maximum error must be.

Comment: Part selection will also involve considerations of noise levels and dynamic response.

Comment: @ Peter Can you tell me how can I calculate error base on opamp information. so I can start from some where.

Comment: @Andy Thanks, This is the answer I was looking for.

Comment: @PeterSmith Could you elaborate on what a "very low Vgs rating" or BJT would do differently?

Answer (score 1):

The load circuit is probably a PRT or BJT for measuring temperature. Thus you don't want to drive the long leads to the sensor and back to the inverting input of the op-amp, it will oscillate. By using a MOSFET, you decouple the feed back making it stabile. The op-amp is easy. The hard part is finding a MOSFET with very low leakage over temperature. A low Vth is typically 0.45V @ 250uA. Remember, we want the MOSFET in the saturated region (Vds > Vgs). So what's happening at 10nA? We don't know, no specs are given at that low of a current. The BJT will have a very low Beta at that current level and thus will be very inaccurate. The sense resistor has iC+iB, so the load current will be iB less than iC. The required accuracy for a DT-670 silicon temperature sensor is 10uA +/- 0.1% (My problem). Also 10Meg ohms requires, clean boards with no contamination.